# Is it OK to subclass solely to provide default state/configuration?

Tags: c#, oop, derived-class, subclassing

Say you have a GUI framework that supports nesting GUI components inside one another.  Let's call the base class for any GUI component that can contain other GUI components a Container.

Is it OK to subclass Container soley to provide default configuration, or should subclassing always provide addition/override/implemented behavior?  For example, say I wanted to make a ButtonBar container that filled up 100% of the screen width, was 50 pixel in height, and laid out its components horizontally.  To configure a Container like that, I could do either of the following two examples:

```
Container container = new Container();
container.PercentWidth = 100;
container.Height = 50;
container.Layout = Layout.Horizontal;

// use container
```

OR, (and this is my question), is it OK to do this:

```
public class ButtonBar : Container
{
    public ButtonBar()
    {
        PercentWidth = 100;
        Height = 50;
        Layout = Layout.Horizontal;
    }
}

ButtonBar buttonBar = new ButtonBar();
// use buttonBar
```

ButtonBar has no additional functionality over a container, and overrides no Container methods.  It just serves to ease configuring a Container to be a ButtonBar.

### Edit

I have concluded that it is probably best to use a factory that returns a Container, such as widgetFactory.CreateButtonBar();  This way, you end up using an abstract type (Container), and encapsulate the 'set-up' of the type in a factory, which is what factories do.

```
public class WidgetFactory
{
    public Container CreateButtonBar()
    {
        Container container = new Container();
        container.PercentWidth = 100;
        container.Height = 50;
        container.Layout = Layout.Horizontal;   

        return container;
    }
}
```

Comment: If consistency is what you're after then it's probably fine...

Comment: this is a relatively common practice in WPF, for example, to apply global styles (in which case you don't even have any code in your child class, it merely has to exist.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is just as correct if some created a subclass just to override a method. One of the main reasons of OOP is for a simple modular design of programs. When you think about it from philosophical stand point your button bar is a different kind of object to a container the difference may seem trivial in a small program but in a larger one it could make the difference of the program being comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually nothing speaks against the approach you're taking. The only problem is see here is that C# has no multi-inheritance so you can only subclass one "Container".

How about instead just holding the container as kinda template and access the properties from that one?

Exampe here

```
public enum ContainerLayout {
    Horizontal,
    Vertical
}

public class Container
{
    public int PercentWidth { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public ContainerLayout Layout { get; set; }
}

public class ButtonBar
{
    public Container containerTemplate = null;

    public ButtonBar(Container strategy)
    {
        containerTemplate = strategy;
    }
}

// Creation would be
ButtonBar btnBar = new ButtonBar(
    new Container()
    {
        PercentWidth = 100,
        Height = 700,
        Layout = ContainerLayout.Horizontal
    }
);
```

Comment: [quote]Actually nothing speaks against the approach you're taking.[/quote]  That's good to hear, and was the answer I was looking for.  

Even though your solution get's rid of ButtonBar inheriting Container, it also get's rid of a ButtonBar being able to be treated as a Container too, which seems undesirable.

Comment: Youre right. Maybe following tge Adapter pattern would yield the result you need and would be a standard approach. Just not sure what you intend to do else with your setup